# IOS Serevr Push Notification For .Net or C#

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS and want to create a server push notification. I had created the certificates and provisioning profiles for development and it is working fine.Now I want to create same for production to upload it to app store.Problem I am facing is :-

1) I am not able to get choose certificate for distribution(i.e APNS certificate for production SSL) while creating provisioning profile.I am only able to get the normal certificate which I am creating.

2)For which certificate I need to develop .p12 file i.e for APNS certi or for Normal certificate.

3)If we are uploading app with a normal certificate how will the apple distinguish whether the app is for Push Notification or for normal uses.

4)For uploading app where to put .p12 file for server side.

5)How to develop server side for free notification sending.

Comment: If you can't get the APNS certificate, you can do nothing. I think you may not have the right to create the APNS certificate, let the agent of your team to help you.

Comment: wll u pls tell me while creating provisioning profile for production which certificate we need or should come while selecting(Select Certificates)?

Comment: You need to read the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) to get the detail.

Comment: You need two certificates, one is for signing the app you submit to app store, the other is used for ***Apple Push Notification service SSL***. The provisioning profile has nothing to do with the certificate used for ***Apple Push Notification service SSL***.